# TSQL: how to eliminate join on Null values when Column value is available

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where i had to join following two table

```
Create Table tbl1(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
Create Table tbl2(col1 int, col2 Varchar)
```

Sample data:

```
 Insert tbl1 Values(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 3, 2), (4, 4, 3)
 Insert tbl2 Values(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (NULL, 'C'), (4, 'D')
```

I used following query:

```
select * 
from tbl1 
Left join tbl2 on tbl1.Col3 = @value 
               and tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col1
```

Later the scenario changed where we have to fetch those value also when tbl1.col1 is null so I used this query:

```
select * 
from tbl1 
Left join tbl2 on tbl1.Col3 = @value 
               and (tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col1 or tbl2.col1 is null)
```

It also worked fine, but the problem is with some of the data where tbl1.col1 has match value as well as null in tbl2.col1. In that case we are getting multiple record which is wrong data.

For example the incorrect o/p is like this:

```
1   1   1       A
1   1   NULL    C
2   2   2       B
2   2   NULL    C
3   3   NULL    C
4   4   NULL    C
4   4   4       D
```

But we want O/P like this

```
1   1   1       A
2   2   2       B
3   3   NULL    C
4   4   4       D
```

My requirement is to fetch matching data from tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col1 or the null values from tbl2.col1 (tbl2.col1 is null) but when tbl2.col1 is not null then the or condition (tbl2.col1 is null) should not be executed.

Kindly suggest me some approach.

Comment: Please format your question properly and provide sample data.

Comment: How do you know `(NULL, 'C')` should only be joined with the record `(3,3,2)`?  What happens with the result if I add `(NULL, 'E')`, in the current query it will be joined with all rows in tbl1. Also if you do `select *`, you should be getting 5 columns in the result.

Comment: what would be the output if in tbl1 you have the 5th row? will the output for the 5th row also 'NULL' ?

Comment: @EdwinStoteler, actually i made mistake in copying the o/p and missed tbl1.col3. Thanks for bringing this into notice. Also "@value" is being passed into my SP as parameter. My o/p is completely dependent on tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2 and tbl2.col1

Comment: Yes @Mark, the o/p should be 5th row also 'NULL' but if there is any matching record for 5th row of tbl1 then 'NULL' in o/p should be eliminated.

Comment: @PS078 would there be a possibility that you have 2 'null' rows in tbl2? then what would be the output if such thing happens?

Comment: Yes @mark, there are possibility of having 2 or more NULLs in tbl2.col1.
Let’s say i have one more record 
Insert tbl2 Values(NULL,'E') 
So the o/p should be 
1 1 1 A <br/>
2 2 2 B <br/>
3 3 NULL C <br/>
3 3 NULL E <br/>
4 4 4 D<br/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we get all values that have a match

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col1
WHERE tbl1.Col3 = @value
```

Then we union all

```
UNION ALL
```

With all the values that are not yet joined

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.col1 IS NULL
WHERE tbl1.Col3 = @value 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * 
      FROM tbl2 tbl2_2
      WHERE tbl1.col2 = tbl2_2.col1)
```

Since this is a stored procedure, you can increase performance by using a temp table to store the results of the first part.

Comment: Thanks @Edwin Stoteler :)